# Snowflake schema with multiple levels

Tags: mondrian, workbench

One of the dimension in my schema is a modeled as an snowflake schema with the following table structure:

```
fact table -> criteria_value -> criteria -> Domain
```

Mondrian schema:

```
<Dimension type="StandardDimension" foreignKey="id_value" highCardinality="false" name="Researched Value">
  <Hierarchy name="Researched Value" hasAll="true" primaryKey="id_va" primaryKeyTable="criteria_value">
    <Join leftAlias="criteria_value" leftKey="id_va" rightAlias="criteria" rightKey="id_c">
      <Table name="criteria_value">
      </Table>
      <Join leftAlias="criteria" leftKey="id_c" rightAlias="domain" rightKey="id_domain">
        <Table name="criteria" alias="">
        </Table>
        <Table name="domain" alias="">
        </Table>
      </Join>
    </Join>
    <Level name="Domain" table="domain" column="desc_d_Eng" type="String" uniqueMembers="true" levelType="Regular" hideMemberIf="Never">
    </Level>
    <Level name="Criteria" table="criteria" column="desc_c_Eng" uniqueMembers="false">
    </Level>
    <Level name="Value" table="criteria_value" column="desc_va_Eng" uniqueMembers="false">
    </Level>
  </Hierarchy>
</Dimension>
```

The problem is that  when trying with an MDX query in Mondrian Workbench :

```
{[Researched Value].[Mobile services].operator} ON ROWS
```

i can get see the values corresponding
("Mobile services" and "operator" are the first members of  levels "Domain" and " Criteria" respectively

but when trying for example:

```
{[Researched Value].[Mobile services].internet} ON ROWS
```

I got:

> Mondrian Error:MDX object '[Researched Value].[Mobile
>   services].[internet]' not found in cube 'Recherche'

while "internet" is a member in "criteria" level (but it's not the first one)

Why can't I see all members of my levels?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're missing the level's name in your MDX identifier. The correct syntax would be:

```
[Hierarchy Name].[Level Name].[Member Name] (.[Child Member Name])
```

Try this instead:

```
{[Researched Value].[Criteria].[Internet]}
```